# Android Studio - Why might requireViewById(R.id.recyclerview) not be working in API 22 (it is in 28)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In short, API 28 all is well; API 22 app crashes in `MainActivity.onCreate` with

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method requireViewById`

on the following line:

`RecyclerView recyclerView = requireViewById(R.id.recyclerview);`

**Now, the long explanation:**

I am setting up an Android Studio app. I have one MVVM "set" including a `RecyclerView` (within an `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`) in my `activity_main.xml`; the `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView` has a `tools:listitem="@layout/parcel_item"`; the `parcel_item.xml` is an `android.support.v7.widget.CardView`.

Everything seems fine under API 28. When I run to API 22 - either on my physical Samsung Galaxy Note tablet (Android 5.1.1 API 22), or on a virtual Nexus 7 (2012) API 22 - the app is crashing almost immediately. In `MainActivity.onCreate`:

`RecyclerView recyclerView = requireViewById(R.id.recyclerview);`

with:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.zazzem.thatsthat, PID: 5613
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method requireViewById(I)Landroid/view/View; in class Lcom/zazzem/thatsthat/MainActivity; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.zazzem.thatsthat.MainActivity' appears in /data/app/com.zazzem.thatsthat-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk)
        at com.zazzem.thatsthat.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

The problem, `No virtual method requireViewById` seems to imply a virtual method that wasn't overridden somewhere, but - as I mentioned before - this works fine under API 28.

I've found nothing online specific to "No virtual method requireViewById" and I've tried everything suggested by a variety of posts relating to "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError" - including **File | Invalidate Caches/Restart** and checking my Gradle scripts (as well as I'm able; I'm very new to Android Studio & java). All to no avail.

**MainActivity.java**

```
//MainActivity.java
package com.zazzem.thatsthat;

import android.arch.lifecycle.Observer;
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ParcelViewModel parcelViewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.d("##","before"); //this I get <<====================
        RecyclerView recyclerView = requireViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        Log.d("##","after"); //this I don't <<====================
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        final ParcelAdapter adapter = new ParcelAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        parcelViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ParcelViewModel.class);
        parcelViewModel.getAllParcels().observe(this, new Observer<List<Parcel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Parcel> parcels) {
                adapter.setParcels(parcels);
            }
        });
    }

    public void menuButtonClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "menuButtonClick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
} //MainActivity
```

**Help | Check for Updates...** all current

**Versions and such:**

Android Studio 3.3.2

SDK Platforms:

-Android 9.0 (Pie) 28 (Revision 6) Installed
-Android 8.1 (Oreo) 27 (Revision 3) Partially installed
-Android 5.1 (Lollipop) 22 (Revision 2) Partially installed

SDK Tools:

-Android SDK Build-Tools 29-rc2
-Android Emulator b28.0.25
-Android SDK Platform-Tools v28.0.2
-Android SDK Tools v26.1.1
-Support Repository (all 4 installed: -,-,47.0.0,58)

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/facadeLight"
        tools:listitem="@layout/parcel_item" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/button_menu"
        ...
        android:tint="@color/facadeLight" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**parcel_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/parcel_theme">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_Descr"
            ...
            android:textSize="60sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_ParcelID"
            ...
            android:textSize="12sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_NrPuzzles"
            ...
            android:textSize="20sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_AdCopy"
            ...
            android:text="Ad Copy" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

finally, the Gradle Scripts:

**build.gradle (Project: ThatsThat)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and **build.gradle (Module: app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.zazzem.thatsthat"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    //Lifecycle components
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    annotationProcessor 'android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1'

    //Room components
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'
    annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1'
}
```

Comment: That stack trace is saying that the issue is in `DepotActivity`, not `MainActivity`. Does `DepotActivity` perhaps extend plain `Activity`, rather than `AppCompatActivity`? That would explain why it's crashing on the old API level, but not the newer one.

Comment: I have two versions here: "Depot" and "Main". That was my bad in preparing the post. (It's been corrected.) Good catch, though

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by having two versions, but what I pointed out in my first comment still seems the likeliest issue. Are you certain that whatever `Activity` you're running to get that stack trace is actually an `AppCompatActivity`, and not just a plain `Activity`? Also, do you really mean to use `requireViewById()`? As the answers below kind of allude to, there's another option that's been around since the beginning.

Comment: Oop, never mind. That's my bad. They've not add `requireViewById()` to `AppCompatActivity`. It's in `ActivityCompat`. Yeah, you'll have to use `findViewById()` to call like that, unless you'd really rather use the `ActivityCompat` helper method, but there's little reason to, I'd say.

Comment: @Mike M. Yes. I am converting a Delphi App to Android Studio. I called my MainActivity DepotActivity to correspond to what I had before. I changed it back before posting here. But, I had grabbed the stack trace first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's findViewById not requireViewById

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = requireViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
```

should be:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
```

Also if you are using MVVM, you may benefit from looking into the data binding library :)

Comment: that fixed it. thanks. also, I am looking at the Data Binding Library stuff now. thanks again. I tried voting - not enough reputation yet...

Answer (score 2):

It's simple, `requireViewById` was added in API level 28, so the error message:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method requireViewById
```

should be read literally -- on runtimes running API level less than 28, this method simply does not exist. Normally, this type of thing would be a compile error, however in this case the error is not raised at compile time, because you are compiling against a library that does have that method. However, the method is not present in runtime versions of the Android API < 28.

From: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#requireViewById(int):

[image: Snippet from Reference Docs]

Answer (score 1):

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
```

You have to update above line.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the response given by @Raman, you could use this extension:

```kotlin
fun <T: View> View.requireExistentViewById(id: Int): T = when {
    Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P -> requireViewById<T>(id)
    else -> findViewById(id) ?: throw IllegalArgumentException()
}
```

Cheers